# Are 'onreadystatechange' , 'readyState' and 'status' implicit properties of javascript function objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When using ajax, we use certain 'words' as the protocol checks in JavaScript. But if I am right then every function is an object in JS. Hence when created a new function instance, e.g.,

> var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

that means we created a new function instance. Now, when doing checks, we write

> xhr.onreadystatechange

and

> xhr.readyState

and also

> xhr.status

etc.  We use dot '.' operator with xhr to reflect them as the properties of readyStateChange() function object. So, ... does it mean that these terms are the implicit properties of the JS function objects?

Thanks

Comment: These are properties inherited from the prototype of `XMLHttpRequest`, not general properties of `Function` objects.

Comment: *that means we created a new function object*  that is wrong. You created an instance of `XMLHttpRequest`, which is a non-function `Object`.

Comment: `we created a new function object.` nope

Comment: If your question is answered, please pick the appropriate answer and mark it correct. If your question is not answered, please leave corresponding comments under the answers.

Comment: Pick your answer!

Comment: i upvoted your answer below but received a message that if i have less then 15 reputation then it doesn't count but is recorded

Answer (score 1):

These are properties inherited from the **prototype** of `XMLHttpRequest`, not general properties of `Function` objects. Also, `new XMLHttpRequest()` returns a non-function `Object`.

```js
let func = new Function()
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

console.log(func.__proto__)
console.log(xhr.__proto__)

console.log(func instanceof Function)
console.log(xhr instanceof Function)
```

Comment: sir can you please make clear ,what is a non-function object?

Comment: `Functions` in Javascript are special Javascript `Object`s that are `runnable`. *Non-function objects*  refers to plain Objects that are not *runnable*.

Answer (score 0):

> **onreadystatechange**,**readyState,responseText,responseXML,status,statusText** are the 6 XMLHttpRequest Object Properties

When we create a prototype of XMLHttpRequest these properties are also inherited with it

**Hence when created a new function instance, e.g.,
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   ???**

No, here we created an object of type XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly achieved through `prototypal inheritance` in javascript.

You can find a lot of info about this on the net, start reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for example.